# Using Subversion with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, svn

I am a member of a team with 3 developers.  We have started using Redmine here for project management and issue tracking and LOVE it.  I have seen elsewhere how nicely Redmine can work when a back-end repository is set up for a project.  There is nice integration all around.

This shop is currently .Net and SQL Server 2005.  I am thinking about recommending a move to Subversion for our VCS (so that we can integrate with Redmine).  I have seen a product called VisualSVN which will make it possible to use Visual Studio with Subversion, so that covers .Net.  But the other big question is if it is possible to configure SQL Server Management Studio to somehow use Subversion for its VCS.  Has anyone done this?

This shop is currently using Sourcegear Fortress.

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on stackoverflow.com, there should be many more users with experience using SQL/SVN.

Comment: From my reading on the topic, the Plugin source control options in SQL Manager are limited. At a stretch, if you are stuck you can generate a script for the database at every major build and use Visual Studio to commit the script at the same time as the rest of your code.

Comment: @Ryan, I had checked stackoverflow too but thanks for the visible reminder to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found any myself so far, but this looked promising:

http://www.jrummell.com/blog/2009/11/sql-server-management-studio-and-tortoisesvn/

This uses the **External Tools** command in SQL Manager to hook into **TortoiseSVN** (VisualSVN uses this so it should be compatible!).

Comment: For my uses, this is probably the best solution for the moment or until Red Gate releases their product.  Thanks for the link.  While not ideal, it removes SSMS from being a blocker to adopting Subversion.

Comment: Updated [link](http://jrummell.azurewebsites.net/sql-server-management-studio-and-tortoisesvn/)

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but can be useful to the thread visitors

SQL Server Management Studio offers an option to use source control by using a Microsoft Source Code Control Interface (MSSCCI) provider. (e.g. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8 )

It enables source control systems to integrate with Windows applications, meaning that by using a MSSCCI provider, the source control functionality is integrated within the application, in this case SQL Server Management Studio, and there is no need for another client to perform source control operations.

A prerequisite for using a MSSCCI provider with SQL Server Management Studio is that either Visual Studio or Team Explorer (the Team Foundation Server client) is installed because the MSSCCI provider relies on Microsoft TFS libraries.

You may also use 3rd party tools, such as ApexSQL Source Control, which is a SQL Server Management Studio SQL source control add-in that has a native support for all major source control systems such as, Mercurial, Git, Perforce, Subversion and Team Foundation Server.

Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/32436729/3809623, to get more details on how to put database into source control with ApexSQL Source Control.

Answer (score 2):

Redgate are bringing out a product called "SQL Source Control"

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/

From a limited try it seems quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked for various different companies using SQL databases for over 15yrs. A tremendous amount of work can go into a large database. I needed a way to track user changes. I'm surprised leveraging the power of source control isn't normal practice in regards to database code.

After some searching, utilities do exist. I found one that fit my needs. It's called [SQL Deploy Manager](http://salsaonchip.com). It was designed to take SQL code files and exported data and rebuild or update a database.

The [quickstart guide](http://www.salsaonchip.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/SoC-QuickStartGuide.pdf) will explain the processes better. I've messaged the developer and he said there are more features planned to automate the setup process. He uses the tool at his data warehouse to deploy code changes across multiple servers. Which a simple DOS batch file you can automate multiple deployments.

Comment: Links are broken. Please update the links.